# System storage keeps on increasing

Tags: mojave, storage

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (Supplement 2).

I have not faced any extraordinary system storage issues like some other posts on the site which say that their system storage is around 150+ GB. However, every now and then I check my system storage usage and the number keeps on increasing. As per my memory, initially (a month ago), system storage usage was around 30 Gigabytes. 2 days back, storage management reported it to be 40 GB. Today, the system storage shows around 42.5 GB used. I don't understand what his happening and since I have a small SSD on my MacBook this storage increase effect is very annoying.

What should be the ideal system storage usage on macOS Mojave? How can I fix this to get back my lost storage? Will upgrading to macOS Catalina further increase system storage usage?

I have installed DaisyDisk as per recommendations on similar questions but I don't see how to 'fix' anything from DaisyDisk. (I am on the trial version)

There is 4 GB of space in 'other volumes' but I haven't partitioned my SSD till date. Is this storage used by the OS as swap?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Note: It would be great if solutions do not require installing 3rd party apps unless necessary, thanks!

Comment: For context, I am looking for more storage because I want to set up virtual machines on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had a computer that I wiped and still had this issue.  I then moved to a machine I had used for years and noticed the system data was also increasing.  I waited longer, and then a lot of the system data was converted into Document data.  So I think as the system was indexing, it labeled my regular data as system data until its indexing was completed.  I might check the problematic machine and see if it relabels the "system data" to be "document" data or other data over time.