# Terminal command to identify and clear runaway system storage

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, storage

Every few months I have moved data out of my mac computer onto a hard drive because of this problem. I now again have this alert in the Terminal: `Your disk space is critically low. Older terminal scrollback contents may be automatically discarded to conserve VM backing store.`:

[image: alert of low disk space]

And this one on the desktop: `Your disk is almost full. Save space by optimising storage`:

[image: alert of full disk]

I click on `Manage` and see that system storage is taking 80 GB on a 128 GB SSD drive:

[image: System information on storage]

I cleared more files yesterday and had 6 GB of storage free. A few hours later, free space went down to 3 GB, all taken by system storage. I will soon have nothing left on the computer but system storage, and then have to reinstall it and go back to the [more normal 10 GB](https://www.comeware.com/clean-huge-system-storage-mac/).

I have run this command to find files larger than 1 GB; it shows only the Spotlight file with 4 GB.

```
$ sudo find /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/ -size +1G  2>/dev/null
Password:
/Volumes/Macintosh HD//.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/CA9AE856-FB94-4765-9028-38E04BEC9683/0.indexArrays
```

What Terminal commands could I run to identify the source of this runaway system storage and to clear it?

**Note**: Similar to the unanswered [System storage keeps on increasing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372078/system-storage-keeps-on-increasing) , except that I provided more textual details on the alert and that I am looking first to identify the issue with a Terminal command.

Comment: Try the cleaning app Onyx to delete caches and run macOS built-in cleaning scripts. Then try a utility like OmniDiskSweeper (free) to find the biggest culprits.

Comment: Any storage related question should be closed as duplicate of 

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space/5360#5360

But in response to your note:

*"except that I provided more textual details on the alert"*

Thank you  for asking a question with all the information! 

*"looking first to identify the issue with a Terminal command."*

If someone has a way to find such info via command line, like using `du` or `wc` or `stat`, that also belongs to the question above.

Comment: Find _where_ the files are, it will be easier to guess what created them. Also, the method of finding files above 1 GB size is not helpful since they can be several 20 MB cookies files too. Firefox does that for example.

Comment: 10 GB free space is nowhere near enough. You will keep hitting this issue all the time [as you have discovered] On any drive you *must* keep 10% free space - ironically, more on a tiny drive. You ought to consider 30GB free on a 128 for a trouble-free life.

Comment: Thanks to all! I tried the common issues on that thread with no result. I used OmniDiskSweeper and found the culprit in GarageBand, and also cleaned up Homebrew. I now have 38 GB free. I added my answer [in the suggested thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space/401050#401050).