# Diagnosing runaway system storage when OmniDiskSweeper fails

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-space

Every few days now, I clear 1-2 GB from my hard drive and still get this alert of low disk space on the desktop:

`Your disk is almost full. Save space by optimising storage`

[image: alert of full disk]

And in the Terminal:

`Your disk space is critically low. Older terminal scrollback contents may be automatically discarded to conserve VM backing store.`:

[image: alert of low disk space]

I click on `Manage` from the desktop and see that system storage is taking 84 GB on a 128 GB SSD drive:

[image: system storage]

OmniDiskSweeper fails to find the large files: the total of files is about 43 GB out of 110 GB used:

[image: OmniDiskSweeper]

The alternative is to keep moving files to an external drive and clear disk space until there is nothing left and I reinstall.

How can I find the culprit of runaway system storage?

*Note*: A few years ago I asked [Terminal command to identify and clear runaway system storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401006/terminal-command-to-identify-and-clear-runaway-system-storage) and solved it with OmniDiskSweeper. Now I have the same issue and cannot find the culprit. I also know about [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my drive space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space) and tried some of the tools there.

### Update

I ran this `du` command on `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`, and here is the list of folders with over 2 GB. `Colossus` is the name of my hard drive. Nothing catches my eye from this list:

```
$ sudo du -h | sort -h
...
2.0G    ./Volumes/Colossus/Library/Application Support/MobileSync
2.0G    ./Volumes/Colossus/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
2.1G    ./Users/mmorin/Library/Application Support/MobileSync
2.1G    ./Users/mmorin/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
2.1G    ./Users/mmorin/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media
2.2G    ./Applications/iMovie.app
2.2G    ./Applications/iMovie.app/Contents
2.2G    ./Users/mmorin/reference
2.3G    ./Users/mmorin/Music
2.3G    ./Users/mmorin/Music/iTunes
2.3G    ./private/var/db
2.4G    ./Users/mmorin/Library/Caches/Homebrew
2.5G    ./Volumes/Colossus/Library/Containers
2.6G    ./usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts
2.7G    ./usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc
3.0G    ./private/var/folders
3.0G    ./private/var/vm
3.2G    ./Library/Application Support/Adobe
3.2G    ./Users/mmorin/Maildir/Cantab/Deleted Items
3.2G    ./Users/mmorin/Maildir/Cantab/Deleted Items/cur
3.2G    ./Volumes/Colossus/Library/Messages
3.6G    ./Users/mmorin/Library/Caches
4.4G    ./Library/Application Support
4.4G    ./Volumes/Colossus/Library/Application Support
4.5G    ./Users/mmorin/Maildir/Cantab
5.2G    ./usr/local/Cellar
5.4G    ./Users/mmorin/Library/Application Support
6.2G    ./Users/mmorin/Maildir
6.2G    ./usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist
6.5G    ./usr/local/texlive
6.5G    ./usr/local/texlive/2020
6.7G    ./Library
6.8G    ./System/Library
6.9G    ./System
8.9G    ./private/var
9.0G    ./private
9.1G    ./.Spotlight-V100
9.1G    ./.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2
9.1G    ./.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/CA9AE856-FB94-4765-9028-38E04BEC9683
9.7G    ./Applications
 13G    ./Users/mmorin/Library
 13G    ./Volumes/Colossus/Library
 15G    ./Volumes
 15G    ./Volumes/Colossus
 16G    ./usr
 16G    ./usr/local
 29G    ./Users
 29G    ./Users/mmorin
```

`Disk Utility` on the container disk shows this:

[image: Disk Utility preview of disk]

Comment: What is the "Colossus" volume? Also, in Disk Utility, if you choose View menu > Show All Devices, and select the "Container disk<something>" in the sidebar, what does it show about the volumes in the container?

Comment: first stop would be to [remove deleted mails and attachments permanently](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mail/mlhlp1001/mac). Maybe its worth considering to change to the [*BasicTeX*-Installation of MacTeX/LiveTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html)? What is /usr/local/Cellar?

Comment: @slartibartfast I removed MacTeX and will install BasicTeX when I need it. This move may buy me a few days or weeks until the runaway storage issues eats that free space again. `/usr/local/Cellar` is where Homebrew installs packages, such as Python3 and Emacs. Is the spotlight index supposed to take 9 GB?

Comment: here is a [short primer on how to uninstall/remove packages via homebrew](https://osxdaily.com/2018/07/29/uninstall-packages-homebrew-mac/). And yes, the Spotlight index seems to occupy to much space. Open _ > System Preferences_, then click _Spotlight_, then the _Privacy_ tab. Drag your internal disk to the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from searching. Wait a bit. Then click the remove button (–) to remove it from the list and start the reindexing.

Comment: or via terminal - type and run the command: _sudo -i_
Enter your administrator password and press Enter. Your Terminal changes to root. Run the commands: _mdutil -Ea_ and _mdutil -ai off_ 
Enter the command _mdutil -ai on_ and press the Return. You will see a message saying that indexing is enabled.

Comment: @slartibartfast That's another 9.1 GB saved thanks to resetting Spotlight. Can you write an answer and include `brew leaves` and `brew remove <package-name>`?

Comment: @miguelmorin what are you specifically deleting to clear up storage? If you are deleting applications installed on your Mac, I recommend using [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to fully delete all files that are associated with the application. I had a similar issue to you and found that files that are associated with my applications are not automatically deleted after I delete the application. This means I had very large amounts of storage taken up by files that had zero purpose. AppCleaner is able to find the associated files and allows you to delete them to free more space.

Comment: @mpp I usually drag them to the trash or run `rm -rf /path/to/application`. Short of installing a third-party app, what directories should one delete to remove the files from installed applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a short (for sure improvable) introduction to regaining storage space on an internal drive**

1. you should use [the `manage`-function Apple provides](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/system-information/syspf9b375b9/mac) to get a rough impression what’s occupying storage. Images, videos, music and podcasts are a good place to start freeing up space - [Apple thinks so too](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996).
2. To get a detailed impression of your system, start with opening a terminal and run `df -h`. The `-h` flag returns a *‘human readable form’* meaning return in the familiar megabyte/gigabyte format. You should see something like this (it is somewhat redundant if you already followed the first point in this list):

   ```
   $ df -h
   Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/disk0s2 128G 122G 6G 95% /
   ```
3. to determine where storage is occupied continue in the terminal and change to the root folder using `cd /` then run  `sudo du -sh * | sort -h` . This will produce a list of file space usage, something like:

   ```
   3.2G    ./Users/your_user/Maildir/your_mailaccount01/Deleted Items
   4.4G    ./Library/Application Support
   4.4G    ./Volumes/Colossus/Library/Application Support
   4.5G    ./Users/your_user/Maildir/
   5.2G    ./usr/local/
   5.4G    ./Users/your_user/Library/Application Support
   6.2G    ./Users/your_user/Maildir
   6.5G    ./usr/local/texlive
   9.1G    ./.Spotlight-V100
   ```

this list might go on and on… In any case you should be able to pinpoint where to start to regain space on the drive.

4. In the above example

   ```
    3.2G    ./Users/your_user/Maildir/your_mailaccount01/Deleted Items
   ```

indicates that there are 3.2Gb of deleted mail items, which are still not removed from the drive. In the Mail app  on your Mac, do one of the following:

- Choose *Mailbox > Erase Deleted Items*, then choose an account.
- In the Mail sidebar, Control-click a *Bin* mailbox, then choose *Erase Deleted Items*. The options differ slightly depending on the MacOS version - see Apple’s guide [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mail/mlhlp1001/mac). If you use another Mail client, please check their manual.

5. next stop in our example would be the TeXLive installation:

   ```
    6.5G    ./usr/local/texlive
   ```

[TeX user group offers BasicTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html), a much smaller alternate TeX Distribution for users who do not want to install the full *TeX Live*. Depending on how TeX Live was installed, you [simply drag the *texlive*-folder to the trash](https://www.tug.org/%7Ekoch/Uninstalling.html) and empty it.

6. or if TeX (or any other program package) was installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) use `brew remove <package-name>`.
7. next the Spotlight index on the example drive:

   ```
    9.1G    ./.Spotlight-V100
   ```

The index size depends of course on how many drives with how many files etc. you assigned to get indexed, but as a "rule of thumb" - if the Spotlight index occupies a few gigabytes something is off and a delete&reindex seems advisable:

- Open * > System Preferences*, then click *Spotlight* , then the *Privacy tab*. Drag your internal disk to the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from searching. Wait a bit. Then click the remove button *(–)* to remove it from the list and start the reindexing.
- Or use the terminal - type and run the command: `sudo -i`, enter your administrator password and press *Enter*. Your Terminal changes to root. Run the commands: `mdutil -Ea` and `mdutil -ai off`. Enter the command `mdutil -ai on` and press the Return. You will see a message saying that indexing is enabled.

8. Make sure [Time Machine backups to external storage](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202784).

For sure this list is neither complete nor in order of importance, but hopefully clear and comprehensible for the few points it provides.

Comment: The Spotlight index and the more lightweight TeX installation were very helpful in reclaiming disk space.

Answer (score 1):

<rant>6.6GB is already critically low remaining space. You need 10-15% free space at minimum, but ironically even more if you only have a small disk. For a teeny 128GB drive, I would be looking to keep at least 20GB free at all times. [It's not really your fault. The disk is too small to be vaguely fit for purpose & all laptop makers ought to be ashamed of themselves for selling computers with such abysmally small storage in the first place. At the time, SSDs were expensive, so it was a cost-cutting exercise. If it's replaceable, replace it with at least a 512. </rant>

OK, more practically, look in Disk Utility & see how much 'Free' space there is compared to 'Available' & 'Purgeable'. Our computers are not vaguely comparable, but look at these 2 figues, in red. The difference is likely to be your actual problem. Running Time Machine might clear some of it, as it will clear your locally stored snapshot backlog.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The figures for me are: `Free 600.5 MB; Available: 600.5 MB  (49 KB purgeable)`.

Comment: You definitely need a bigger drive. That's barely enough for the machine to start up. You urgently need to clear some space. A couple of GB is not enough to clear, you must clear at least 10, more likely 20GB.

Comment: Yes indeed, I've noticed the computer working more slowly and some services are now unable to start. I think the easiest way to clear 20 GB is to identify some of those 80 GB of storage. I added in the question a printout of `du -h` on the startup disk.